# new Date().toLocaleString not working on chrome

Tags: date, google-chrome, timezone

I want to display UTC date '2020-01-14T17:43:37.000Z' in local timezone.

I am getting output like this :-

new Date('2020-01-14T17:43:37.000Z').toLocaleString(undefined, {dateStyle: "medium", timeStyle: 'long'});

**Chrome**

> > 'Jan 14, 2020, 11:13:37 PM GMT+5:30'

**FireFox**

> > 14-Jan-2020, 11:13:37 pm IST

How can i display Date in local timezone consistently accross all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Consistency is not guaranteed with `toLocalString`.  All that's guaranteed is that the output is in a format that is reasonable to display to the user given the options specified.

That said, you can get the result you're looking for if you specify `en-IN` for the locale code, and `Asia/Kolkata` for the time zone.

```js
const result = new Date('2020-01-14T17:43:37.000Z')
  .toLocaleString('en-IN', {
    dateStyle: "medium",
    timeStyle: 'long',
    timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
  });
console.log(result);
```

You probably don't want to hardcode those into your application though.  In your original code, `undefined` means to use the user's default locale, and the absence of `timeZone` means to use the user's default time zone.  If the user happens to have `en-IN` and `Asia/Kolkata`, then they will see the same result as above.

Comment: Raised a chromium bug on this... they are going to fix it